# Upload Youtube API Cordova iOS , Cant Pass Snippet

Tags: ios, cordova, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

im build an apps using cordova, this apps using camera for record video and upload into youtube (using plugin media-capture and filetransfer) , i'v been trying on android and running well , but when im trying on iOS , this apps cant pass snippet parameter, like title and description.

here my JS

```
    var t = document.getElementById("title").value;
         var d = document.getElementById("description").value;
         var namef =document.getElementById("y_name").value;
         var tipe =document.getElementById("y_tipe").value;
         var urif = document.getElementById("y_url").value; //path from video recording

              var searchurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
                          $.ajax({
                              dataType: "json",
                              url: searchurl,
                              data: {
                                  client_id: 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                                  client_secret: 'xxxxx',
                                  refresh_token: 'xxxxxxxx',
                                  grant_type: 'refresh_token'
                              },
                              type: "POST",
                              contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;",
                              crossDomain: true,
                              cache: true,
                              success: function(data) {

                                  alert(t); //showing alert from TITLE,and works at ios

                                  var accessToken = data.access_token;
                                  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                                  options.fileKey = 'file';
                                  options.fileName = namef;
                                  options.mimeType = tipe;
                                  options.chunkedMode = false;
                                  options.headers = {
                                      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                                  };


                      options.params = {
                          "": {
                              snippet: {

                                  title: t,
                                  description: d,
                                  tags: 'Upload-Youtube-Test',
                                  categoryId: 22
                              },
                              status: {
                                  privacyStatus: 'public'
                              }
                          }
                      }; //here problem for iOS

                                  var ft = new FileTransfer();
                                  ft.upload(urif, 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status', function(data) {

                                         console.log(data.response);
              },

                                      function(e) {
                                          console.log('upload error', e);
                                      }, options, true);
                                  ft.onprogress = function(data) {

                                      var currentTime = Date.now();
                                      var bytesUploaded = data.loaded;
                                      var totalBytes = data.total;
                                      var bytesPerSecond = bytesUploaded / ((currentTime - this.uploadStartTime) / 1000);
                                      var estimatedSecondsRemaining = (totalBytes - bytesUploaded) / bytesPerSecond;
                                      var percentageComplete = (bytesUploaded * 100) / totalBytes;
                                      var progre = percentageComplete.toFixed();
                                      console.log(progre);

                                  };
                              },
                          });

                }
```

**and the problem is**

```
   options.params = {
                  "": {
                      snippet: {

                          title: t,
                          description: d,
                          tags: 'Upload-Youtube-Test',
                          categoryId: 22
                      },
                      status: {
                          privacyStatus: 'public'
                      }
                  }
              };
```

for uploading video, yes, success , this apps can upload into youtube, BUT the title on youtube is unknown, which is the param from snippet cant pass. this is same code for android , but why with iOS not work ? even im trying with static Title and description like this:

```
options.params = {
                      "": {
                          snippet: {

                              title: 'Test Title',
                              description: 'Test Desc',
                              tags: 'Upload-Youtube-Test',
                              categoryId: 22
                          },
                          status: {
                              privacyStatus: 'public'
                          }
                      }
                  };
```

this snippet still cant pass into youtube.

Comment: Why is there double quotation marks in your metadata? Is that intended? Isn't that the reason why your snippet body is not being read?

Comment: did you got any solution for this? i am trying since 3 day but not getting title

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed i got